# Binary Search Tree Implementation in C

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I have to implement Treesort, inOrderTraversal, Max, and Height functions. Unsure what is wrong with my code. It builds with no errors or warning but the console is empty.

```
void TreeSort(ElementType *X, long n, SearchTree T){
X = NULL;
for (T = 0; T < n; T++)
    X = Insert(X, T);
}

void inOrderTraversal(SearchTree T){
if (T = NULL)
    return;
inOrderTraversal(T->Left);
printf("%d", T->Element);
inOrderTraversal(T->Right);
}

long Height(SearchTree T){
if (T = NULL)
    return 0;
else
{
    long LHeight = Height(T->Left);
    long RHeight = Height(T->Right);

    if (LHeight > RHeight)
        return LHeight + 1;
    else return RHeight + 1;
}
}

long Max(int left, int right){
if (right = NULL);
int Max = left + 1;
return Max; 
}
```

EDIT: here is the rest of tree.c. Where the above functions are located.

```
struct TreeNode{
ElementType Element;
SearchTree  Left;
SearchTree  Right;
 };

 /* Figure 4.17 Routine to make an empty tree */
 SearchTree MakeEmpty( SearchTree T ){
if( T != NULL ){
    MakeEmpty( T->Left );
    MakeEmpty( T->Right );
    free( T );
}
return NULL;
 }

  /* Figure 4.18 Find operation for binary search trees */
 Position Find( ElementType X, SearchTree T ){
if( T == NULL ) return NULL;
if( X < T->Element ) return Find( X, T->Left );
else if( X > T->Element ) return Find( X, T->Right );
else return T;
}

 /* Figure 4.19 Recursive implementation of FindMin for binary search trees */
 Position FindMin( SearchTree T ){
if( T == NULL ) return NULL;
else if( T->Left == NULL ) return T;
else return FindMin( T->Left );
}

 /* Figure 4.20 Nonrecursive implementation of FindMax for binary search trees */
 Position
 FindMax( SearchTree T ){
if( T != NULL )
    while( T->Right != NULL )T = T->Right;

return T;
}

 /* Figure 4.22 Insertion into a binary search tree */
 SearchTree Insert( ElementType X, SearchTree T ){
 /* 1*/ if( T == NULL ){
        /* Create and return a one-node tree */
 /* 2*/     T = malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode ) );
 /* 3*/     if( T == NULL ) FatalError( "Out of space!!!" );
        else{
 /* 5*/         T->Element = X;
 /* 6*/         T->Left = T->Right = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if( X < T->Element ) T->Left = Insert( X, T->Left );
    else if( X > T->Element ) T->Right = Insert( X, T->Right );
    /* Else X is in the tree already; we'll do nothing */
  /*11*/    return T;  /* Do not forget this line!! */
 }

 /* Figure 4.25 Deletion routine for binary search trees */
 SearchTree Delete( ElementType X, SearchTree T ){
Position TmpCell;

if( T == NULL ) Error( "Element not found" );
else if( X < T->Element )  /* Go left */
    T->Left = Delete( X, T->Left );
else if( X > T->Element )  /* Go right */
    T->Right = Delete( X, T->Right );
/* Found element to be deleted */
else if( T->Left && T->Right ){  /* Two children */
    /* Replace with smallest in right subtree */
    TmpCell = FindMin( T->Right );
    T->Element = TmpCell->Element;
    T->Right = Delete( T->Element, T->Right );
}
else{  /* One or zero children */
    TmpCell = T;
    /* Also handles 0 children */
    if( T->Left == NULL ) T = T->Right; 
    else if( T->Right == NULL ) T = T->Left;
    free( TmpCell );
}
return T;
}

 ElementType Retrieve( Position P ){
return P->Element;
 }
```

Main Function

```
SearchTree T=MakeEmpty(NULL);
long *array;
long i;
long j;
long heightSum=0;
float avgHeight;

#ifdef PART_A
array=permutation(N);
TreeSort(array, N, T);
free(array);
```

Comment: There's no main function

Comment: What does your compiler tell you when you try to compile this?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I did not add the main function to this post. The main function callas TreeSort and frees the array. The functions above are in a tree.c file where the structure Treenode is defined.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes the console says "Press any key to continue"

Comment: Well this is insufficient information. Where are you calling your function? is `T->Element` an integer? are you initializing each node with NULL values for left and right (common mistake)?

Comment: @EOF The build succeeds, no errors or warnings. Console says Press Any Key To Continue

Comment: @JohnnyLamanuzzi: Well, either you haven't posted all relevant code, or your compiler is broken.

Comment: @JohnnyLamanuzzi: Ah. I take that back: You haven't posted all relevant code **and** your compiler is broken.

Comment: `if (T = NULL)` --> `if (T == NULL)` also `for (T = 0; T < n; T++)` is wrong.